# Android Linear Layout always gives gab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I have been trying to make layout for Android with small bottom and right bar, rest of the screen should be relative layout. However, I am still getting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdrIL.png)

I would like to get both "light orange" bars to the bottom/right border and the rest should be filled with either image or video.

Bellow is my code, can you help me with finding the mistake?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8333"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.8333">

            <VideoView 
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.1667"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1667"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Milan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8333"
        android:layout_gravity="top">        
        <ViewFlipper android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8333"
            android:layout_gravity="top">
            <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:contentDescription="hello"/>
        </ViewFlipper>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/rightImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.1667"
            android:contentDescription="hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1667"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:contentDescription="hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Good. Then please set the answer.